# Losing sub classes' properties in a collection of inherited classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I am trying to implement a relatively easy class hierarchy. However, it seems some of my knowledge are lost since school.. The problem is that the subclasses' properties are lost on retrieval.

The hierarchy is as follows:

- An abstract class with general properties about the subclasses
- Subclasses with specific properties. Inherits from the abstract class
- A collection of the subclasses

**Collection**

```
public class ActiveFilters
{
    public List<ActiveFilter> Filters { get; set; }
    enum FilterTypes 
    { 
        DateRange = 1,
        CheckBox = 2,
        TextBox = 3,
        RadioButtons = 4
    };

    public ActiveFilters()
    {
        Filters = new List<ActiveFilter>();

        //Required filters on start
        Filters.Add(
            new FilterDateRange(
                "/statistikstart.aspx",
                (int)FilterTypes.DateRange,
                "paymentDate",
                new DateTime(1800, 1, 1),
                DateTime.Now.AddDays(7)
            )
        );
        Filters.Add(
            new FilterDateRange(
                "/statistikgiro.aspx",
                (int)FilterTypes.DateRange,
                "paymentDate",
                new DateTime(1800, 1, 1),
                DateTime.Now
            )
        );
    }

    public ActiveFilter GetActiveFilter(string source, string name)
    {
        try
        {
            return Filters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Source == source && x.Name == name) as ActiveFilter;
        }
        catch
        {
            //Filter not in collection
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Abstract class**

```
public abstract class ActiveFilter
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**A subclass**

```
public class FilterDateRange : ActiveFilter
{
    public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }

    public FilterDateRange(string source, int type, string name, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        base.Source = source;
        base.Type = type;
        base.Name = name;
        this.FromDate = FromDate;
        this.ToDate = ToDate;
    }
}
```

When I try to retrieve one of the created filters from the collection constructor, no dates are saved from the subclass. The only information that is saved are the properties of the abstract class:

```
FilterDateRange test = ((FilterDateRange)((ActiveFilters)Session["activeFilters"]).GetActiveFilter("/statistikstart.aspx", "paymentDate"));
```

Is the problem that I return ActiveFilter from GetActiveFilter() instead of the sub class? if so, how can I rewrite the GetActiveFilter() to return filters when the filters can be of different subclasses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some typos:

```
public FilterDateRange(string source, int type, string name, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    base.Source = source;
    base.Type = type;
    base.Name = name;
    this.FromDate = FromDate; // set FromDate to FromDate (the property) 
    this.ToDate = ToDate;
}
```

should be

```
public FilterDateRange(string source, int type, string name, DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    base.Source = source;
    base.Type = type;
    base.Name = name;
    this.FromDate = fromDate; // set FromDate to fromDate (the parameter)
    this.ToDate = toDate;
}
```

Comment: Wow, now I feel silly.. I probably wouldn't have seen it myself anyway, so thank you!